# Using onClickListerner() on EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I am trying to make an android app for keeping a tab on fuel consumption. I have 4 EditText viz.

1. Km reading
2. Fuel Quantity
3. Fuel price
4. Total cost

Km reading input is compulsory, while amongst the rest 3 any two are required from the user. So when the user clicks the 3rd Edittext he automatically gets the calculated value acquired with the help of the other two..Help?

---

Hi!

Thank you all for all the suggestions.. And no i did not want you all to work for me. I tried asking the question here for the first time.I figured it our myself and heres the code so it might prove helpful for anybody who needs it in future.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.fuelexpense);

    ETKm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETKm);
    ETFuelQty = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETFuelQty);
    ETFuelPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETFuelPrice);
    ETTotalCost = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETTotalCost);
    btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    chkFullTank = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkFullTank);


    btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);



    ETFuelQty.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    ETFuelPrice.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    ETTotalCost.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

}

```
public void onFocusChange(View EditTextFocus , boolean hasFocus)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        km= Long.parseLong(ETKm.getText().toString());
        fuelQty= Integer.parseInt(ETFuelQty.getText().toString());
        fuelPrice= Double.parseDouble(ETFuelPrice.getText().toString());
        totalCost= Double.parseDouble(ETTotalCost.getText().toString());
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ne)
    {
        ne.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(ETTotalCost.hasFocus())
        {

            if((fuelQty!=0)&&(fuelPrice!=0))
            totalCost=fuelQty*fuelPrice;
        ETTotalCost.setText(newDecimalFormat("##.##").format(totalCost));
        }   

    else if(ETFuelQty.hasFocus())
        {
            if((fuelPrice!=0)&&(totalCost!=0))
                fuelQty= (int) (totalCost/fuelPrice);
                ETFuelQty.setText(String.valueOf(fuelQty));
        }   

    else if(ETFuelPrice.hasFocus())
        {
            if((fuelQty!=0)&&(totalCost!=0))
                fuelPrice=totalCost/fuelQty;
                ETFuelPrice.setText(String.valueOf(fuelPrice));
        }   

    }
```

WOrked for me.. Thanks again

Comment: So you are asking for the code that does what you describe? Because I don't see a question anywhere!

Comment: show what you have tried .Put  some code then only somebody can help

Comment: You need to show us what you tried. We do not and will not do work for you. We will try to help you solve an issue but only after you show us the work and you explain your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need `onClickListener` for `EditText`, it is mainly needed for buttons. For EditText you can use `setOnTouchListener`. Then in `onTouch` check whether previous fields are filled. If not, show error else do the calculation.
Read the basics first before trying to develop any app otherwise you will miss many important concepts.

Comment: did my answer helped you? if so, mark the answer useful and tick the check to mark question solved.

Comment: and one thing more from now on try to provide a bit of code to specify the problem. It show us that atleast you tried.